# How to change a variable when touching a pen drawing?

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm making a game in Scratch where if they touch something their HP goes down. I'm planning on making multiple of the sprite appear without having to use clones or make several of the same sprite so I'm using the pen extension to draw it. I'm running into a problem though. When I tell it to change the variable by touching the sprite, the pen copy doesn't count as it so it won't change it. How do you make the variable change when touching the pen?

The main reason I don't plan on using clones is due to Scratch's 300 clone limit. I intend on having more than 300 of the thing i'm making, which would go over Scratch's clone limit and why most people use the pen to get around that. The answer marked as accepted technically solves the problem until that point so I marked it as correct.

Comment: I think you'd have to either check the color, or put an invisible object over the pen drawing. Maybe there's other options but those seem like the most straightforward. Probably having the invisible clones is the better option. You'd have to make sure they get deleted at the right time of course.

Comment: I did try the color trick but then ran into another problem. It's a gaster blaster since i'm making a Error404 Sans Fan Fight, but as it fades out it apparently no longer counts as the same color. The invisible clones may work assuming you mean they are there as a kind of hitbox, and I could try to experiment with it.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the clones could be a hitbox. Worth a try.

Comment: I tried it when I could and it works almost perfectly!

Comment: To rule out the possibility that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you please explain _why_ you intend to work "without having to use clones"? Preferably by editing your question and describing your problem in more detail there.

Comment: I say I don't want to work with clones mainly because I plan on having over 300 of them, which is the clone limit on scratch. The reason the clone hitbox worked for this is because I didn't get to the part where I plan to have over 300, when I do get there im going to have to find a way to make this happen but over 300 times. Don't ask why I plan on having 300 of the same thing I have it planned out lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of providing a formal answer to this question, I'll just rehash the comments above.

A solution that worked ended up being to create an invisible (via the ghost effect) clone that goes over each pen drawing - each clone acting like a hitbox.

Comment: Please define 'invisible'. I tried: (1) the 'hide' block, (2) ghost effect 100, (3) change all colors to 'transparent' in the costume editor. Only the ghost effect worked.

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks for the additional info, I updated my answer. Although I would've been fine if you'd edited it yourself, just so you know.

Comment: How do envision this idea being used in practice? You'd either need a clone for each pen drawing (which defies the whole point of using pen to reduce the number of clones), or have a single clone jump around between pen drawings (which brings quite some coding overhead to guide the clone, based on coordinate lists). Either way, it seems like overkill, unless OP plans on having more clones than Scratch's maximum of 300.

Comment: @RuudHelderman I don't really know, I gave a vague suggestion and didn't think about it much further and apparently it worked. Feel free to edit my answer or post a new one with a better idea; this was just *an* idea that worked in *this* case. I didn't elaborate because OP didn't provide any additional info on how their implementation worked. The question was pretty vague and broad and so I gave a similarly vague and broad answer, I'm not trying to spend all day coming up with a perfectly ideal optimal solution. If you have the time to do that, by all means, do it, I'm not stopping you.

Comment: @RuudHelderman as a matter of fact I do plan on going over the limit of 300 lol

Comment: And while I know having the hitbox as a clone itself does defy the point, it technically solves the problem I asked.

Comment: Coming back and looking at this nearly 1 and a half years later... What was I doing???????

Comment: @ChocolateChara Well did you end up going with any of the solutions discussed here?

Comment: Well I marked this one as the answer lol and I went and found the project and it seems to work so cool ig I completely forgot about this though lol

Comment: I'm just slightly confused why I asked if the answer ended up using clones anyway and still worked but oh well, thanks :P

Comment: @ChocolateChara I came up with a way better solution anyway and posted it as an answer; I know you don't need it anymore but maybe it'll be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to handle more than 300 objects in Scratch without using clones is to manage the objects using lists, clear and redraw objects on the stage each frame, and detect collisions by looping through the object positions and checking distances. I've just devised a method that handles object creation, removal, drawing, fading, and collision detection efficiently using lists and a single sprite.

1. **Object management**: Maintain a list containing the position (X and Y coordinates) of each object created in the scene. To handle objects fading out, create a separate list to keep track of a fade timer for each individual object. The fade timer determines the opacity of the corresponding object.
2. **Drawing objects**: Each frame, use a sprite to clear all the object stamps on the stage. After clearing, loop through the object positions list and move the sprite to each object's position sequentially. Update the sprite's opacity based on the fade timer list and use the stamp block to redraw the object at the updated position and opacity. Repeat this process for each frame, ensuring that objects are only redrawn if the list of objects has changed or if their opacity must be updated.
3. **Collision detection**: Detect collisions by looping through the object positions list and calculating the distance between each X and Y point and the sprite that needs to check for collisions. If the distance is below a certain threshold (i.e., the objects are close enough), consider it as a collision and perform the necessary actions.

Here is pseudocode of the solution:

```
Initialize object_positions list
Initialize fade_timers list

Function create_object(x, y):
    Add x to object_positions list
    Add y to object_positions list
    Add initial_fade_timer to fade_timers list

Function remove_object(index):
    Remove item at index from object_positions list (X coordinate)
    Remove item at index from object_positions list (Y coordinate)
    Remove item at index from fade_timers list

Function update_and_draw_objects():
    Clear object stamps

    For i in range(0, length(object_positions), 2): # Step by 2 for X and Y pairs
        x_position = object_positions[i]
        y_position = object_positions[i + 1]
        fade_timer = fade_timers[i // 2]

        Move sprite to (x_position, y_position)

        Set sprite opacity based on fade_timer
        Stamp sprite

        Update fade_timer in fade_timers list (e.g., decrease it)

Function check_collision(sprite_x, sprite_y):
    For i in range(0, length(object_positions), 2): # Step by 2 for X and Y pairs
        x_position = object_positions[i]
        y_position = object_positions[i + 1]

        distance_to_object = calculate_distance(sprite_x, sprite_y, x_position, y_position)

        If distance_to_object < collision_threshold:
            Perform necessary actions (e.g., decrease HP, remove object)
```

Usage example:

```
Create objects as needed:
    create_object(new_object_x, new_object_y)

Remove objects as needed:
    remove_object(object_index)

Repeatedly execute in each frame:
    update_and_draw_objects()
    check_collision(colliding_sprite_x, colliding_sprite_y)
```

The key advantage of this approach is that it requires only one sprite to handle creation, removal, drawing, fading, and collision detection for all the objects, completely eliminating the need for clones. This is achieved by managing the objects and their properties using lists, efficiently clearing and redrawing the objects each frame, and detecting collisions by calculating the distance between object positions.